# VirtualBox -Linux Mint Cinnamon crashes

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint, cinnamon

I dual boot Windows and Linux Mint on the same computer.  I spend most of my time in Windows, only occasionally rebooting to Mint.  I got tired of rebooting and set up a VirtualBox VM to launch my Mint OS from a raw disk.  After logging in, I get the error message "Cinnamon has crashed.  You are currently running in fallback mode. Do you want to restart Cinnamon yes/no"  If I click yes, the error just comes back.  If I say no, I am put into a Gnome2 (?) session.  I tried installing the Guest Additions software, but that didnt help.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Obviously, I would like it to work both in a VM and booting straight into Mint.

Comment: I said it defaulted me to  Gnome2

Comment: I am wondering why you want me to do that?  what information are you looking for?

Comment: linux isnt my strong suit.  i ctrl-f2 to console, but i dont see gnome or x.  if i startx, i just launches x with cinnamon and the same error happens.

Comment: nothing stands out as an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up trying to get it to work with Cinnamon.  I just installed LXDE and use that in VB.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem on my Linux Mint work computer. My problem was that while updating packages something went wrong. So in my case I ran:

```
sudo apt install --fix-broken
```

A whole lot of pacakges had to be fixed. one of them cinnamon-settings-daemon which probably caused this error for me.

LXDE is much more lightweight, so not a bad choice either!